# Importing Yiic-generated controller to existing NetBeans Project

Tags: netbeans, controller, yii

I created a controller in command prompt with 'yiic' and noticed it wasn't included in the NetBeans directory tree. So, I had to manually cut/paste the generated files and folders into the directory tree. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using netbeans 7.0.1 and given that you generate controller in same directory it automatically adds to opened project in net beans

Comment: I think the issue is that I previously imported my project files from C:\demo to C:\xampp\htdocs\demo, and using yiic within the xampp folder did not update the project. So, I had to run yiic within the actual project folder, not where source files were copied to. Thanks